# Manager-managed vs member-managed standards of conduct in WY LLC law

Tags: limited-liability-company

[Wyoming LLC law 17-29-409](https://law.justia.com/codes/wyoming/2019/title-17/chapter-29/article-4/section-17-29-409/) says:

```
(g) In a manager-managed limited liability company, the following rules apply:

    (i) Subsections (a), (b), (c) and (e) of this section 
          apply to the manager or managers  and not the members;
```

Note that this specifically says that it applies to a "manager-managed" LLC, (and thus by definition not a member-managed LLC).

However, subsections (a), (b), and (c) that are referred to by this, explicitly state that they apply to "a **member**-managed" LLC, (thus not a "manager-managed" LLC).  For example:

```
(a) A member of a member-managed limited liability company owes to the company and, 
    subject to W.S. 17-29-901(b), 
    the other members the fiduciary duties of loyalty and care 
    stated in subsections (b) and (c). 

...
```

**Is there a possible mistake in this Wyoming law?**  Because I think as it is for example, (a) is for a member-managed LLC, so how can (g)(i) apply to it?

**Did they possibly intend to say** that in (g)(i) that subsections **(a), (b) and (c) now also apply to a manager-managed LLC**?

OR,

when they say to essentially substitute 'manager' for 'member' does this also include inside the term 'member-managed' to change it to 'manager-managed'?  I just assumed that 'member-managed' and 'manager-managed' were terms unto themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read this as providing that in a "member-managed" LLC subsections (a), (b), and (c) apply to all the members, but in a "manager-managed" LLC they apply only to the managers, not to members who are not managers. That would not be a contradiction or a mistake, and seems reasonable and logical.